# .NET Client unable to connect with AWS RabbitMQ | TLS server: In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:346 generated SERVER ALERT

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, rabbitmq, tls1.2

I am using a RabbitMQ hosted on AWS (RMQ Version: 3.10.10, Erlang Version: 25.1.1).

When I tried connecting to this MQ from our servers i am getting the following errors on the cloudwatch logs for AWS RabbitMQ

> TLS server: In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:346 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Insufficient Security - no_suitable_ciphers

> TLS server: In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:364 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Protocol Version

> TLS server: In state hello at tls_record.erl:564 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Unexpected Message - {unsupported_record_type,71}

On Client Side, the application that uses this MQ is a .NET Framework v4.8 Windows Service.
The Client Servers are running Windows 2008 Server R2 Edition.
(This issue is not reproducible in Servers running Windows 2016 Server Edition. Also I cant update the OS of these old servers so please don't suggest that).

The following code is implemented on client side

```
string ExternalRabbitMQClient = "ampqs://xxxx.aws.com";
Uri uri = new Uri(ExternalRabbitMQClient);
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
      Uri = new Uri(ExternalRabbitMQClient),
      UserName = "username",
      Password = "password",
      Ssl = new SslOption()
      {
          Enabled = true,
      }
};
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

The exception message I get when I tried to run this code is

> None of the specified endpoints were reachable. One or more errors occurred. A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.

I have verified that server has TLS 1.2 enabled and i have also tried adding the following lines in connectionfactory or just before creating connection to no avail.

```
AmqpUriSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Really hopeful to get solutions or ways to investigate/debug this issue to find and fix this issue.

Comment: Please provide your unabridged RabbitMQ configuration. Also, please note that the RabbitMQ team monitors the `rabbitmq-users` [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow.